# .NET 8/MAUI Build Issues preventing migration on Android

Tags: .net, xamarin, build, maui, .net-8.0

I have been working on a migration project and have successfully migrated from Xamarin Forms to .NET 7 MAUI. However, there are limitations when trying to work with iOS on .NET 7 after you have upgraded your Mac machine.

I have started with the migration from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and no matter what I try, I keep getting the same issue currently when targeting Android as a standalone platform (I will combine iOS and Android as two target platforms one I resolve the current problems).

The error being generated is:

```
Task "GenerateJavaStubs"
         Assembly loaded during TaskRun (Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs): Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers, Ver
         sion=7.0.0.129, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065 (location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.An
         droid.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.dll, MVID: 1f7aa271-c339-4f84-bbc7-79f67ba3956
         0, AppDomain: [Default])
         Assembly loaded during TaskRun (Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs): System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo, Version=8.0.
         0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a (location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\
         8.0.1\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll, MVID: 98488d15-0385-47eb-9c39-1c1e0766d664, AppDomain: [Default])
     2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error
       XAGJS7003: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'asm') [C:\Users\edwar\source\repos\MAUI\Skill
       web.Maui\Skillweb.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error
       XAGJS7003:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.XAAssemblyResolver.CacheEntry..ctor(TaskLoggingHelper log, String filePath, Assem
       blyDefinition asm, AndroidTargetArch arch) [C:\Users\edwar\source\repos\MAUI\Skillweb.Maui\Skillweb.Maui.csproj::TargetF
       ramework=net8.0-android]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error
       XAGJS7003:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.XAAssemblyResolver.Load(AndroidTargetArch arch, String filePath, ReaderParameters
        readerParameters) [C:\Users\edwar\source\repos\MAUI\Skillweb.Maui\Skillweb.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error
       XAGJS7003:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(XAAssemblyResolver res, Boolean useMarshalMethods) [C:\User
       s\edwar\source\repos\MAUI\Skillweb.Maui\Skillweb.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error
       XAGJS7003:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.RunTask() [C:\Users\edwar\source\repos\MAUI\Skillweb.Maui\Skill
       web.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1513,3): error
       XAGJS7003:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/
       xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 25 [C:\Users\edwar\source\repos\MAUI\Ski
       llweb.Maui\Skillweb.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
       Done executing task "GenerateJavaStubs" -- FAILED.
```

I have searched everywhere and have yet to get a conclusive solution and the suggestions include one or all of the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
</PropertyGroup>
```

OR

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\BuildFolder</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

OR

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
    <EnableTrimAnalyzer>False</EnableTrimAnalyzer>
    <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Basically, nothing works.

The expectation would be to have both target platform successfully build and ready for deployment when required using .NET 8 so that I can conclude debugging NFC for iOS using hardware.

Presently, using .NET 7 and the latest versions of Xcode, it is not possible to debug on a physical device for iOS.

I have also attached the project file (removed relevant stuff) for anyone wanting to see what it looks like.

NB! You will note that I am targeting .NET 7 and .NET 8 in this version, which is just one of the things I am trying to see if I can get to debug on an iOS device.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
    <!--<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>-->
    <!--<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>-->
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Namespace Name</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <TitleProduct Name</Title>
    <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>Product Name</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>---</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>---</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>2.2024.0111</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>2003</ApplicationVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">15.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">29.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

    <IncrementVersionOnBuild>2.yyyy.MM.MMdd</IncrementVersionOnBuild>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.2024.0115.2112</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>2.2024.0115.2112</FileVersion>
    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <!--<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>.sonarlint\skillweb.maui_skillweb.maui_ayfmhccthtlehxqfuhtfcsharp.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>-->
</PropertyGroup>    

<!--<PropertyGroup>
    <UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
</PropertyGroup>-->
<!--<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\BuildFolder</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>-->

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-android|AnyCPU'">
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>True</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
    <!--<AndroidEnableMarshalMethods>False</AndroidEnableMarshalMethods>-->
</PropertyGroup>

<!--<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
    <EnableTrimAnalyzer>False</EnableTrimAnalyzer>
    <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>-->

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
    <ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>true</ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>
    <BuildIpa>False</BuildIpa>
    <OptimizePNGs>True</OptimizePNGs>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
    <BuildIpa>True</BuildIpa>
    <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
    <MtouchExtraArgs>--optimize:-static-block-to-delegate-lookup</MtouchExtraArgs>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
    <ProvisioningType>automatic</ProvisioningType>
    <CodesignKey>---</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>---</CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-android'">
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="Platforms\Android\google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
    <BundleResource Include="Platforms\iOS\GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('net8.0'))">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.3" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui" Version="8.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="CoreCLR-NCalc" Version="3.0.119" />
    <PackageReference Include="FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient" Version="4.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microcharts" Version="0.9.5.9" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision" Version="6.0.0-dev.20190919.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face" Version="2.8.0-preview.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="3.0.0-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.PdfViewer" Version="24.1.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Pdf.NET" Version="24.1.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Maui" Version="6.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download" Version="0.11.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging" Version="8.10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="5.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('net7.0'))">
    <PackageReference Include="BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui" Version="7.0.0.1-pre" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="CoreCLR-NCalc" Version="3.0.119" />
    <PackageReference Include="FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient" Version="4.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microcharts" Version="0.9.5.9" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision" Version="6.0.0-dev.20190919.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face" Version="2.8.0-preview.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="7.0.96" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.PdfViewer" Version="23.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Pdf.NET" Version="23.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Maui" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download" Version="0.11.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging" Version="8.10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="5.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="123.3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision" Version="120.1.3.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision.Common" Version="119.1.3.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.Ktx" Version="1.8.2" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.png" Color="#1F669C" Resize="true" />
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#1F669C" BaseSize="256,256" Resize="true" />
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\**" />
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\**" />
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="README.md">
    <Pack>True</Pack>
    <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: What was your first problem on .net7.0? If one migration didn't work for you, doing a second one (which could cost a lot of effort) on top of it won't help you... Also share csproj here

Comment: @o_w I migrated from Xamarin Forms to MAUI .NET 7 and managed to get everything working successfully except for NFC on iOS because of NFC on iOS, we made the decision to upgrade to .NET 8. So, no major issues on .NET 7 other than the fact that I am not able to connect a device and debug. With .NET 8, no matter what I try, it keeps failing with the errors shown.

Comment: Was NFC related to not being able to debug? The error you're showing is about Android, not iOS. Could you share your csproj, and also did you try open new empty Maui project and debug on your physical iPhone?

Comment: @o_w NFC is part of the problem, but I want to get Android resolved first because it is blocking me from getting to debug NFC, because as of now, iOS does build.

I can confirm that iOS builds and deploys just fine. With Android, still having issues even with a new solution and strange thing is that .NET 7 works fine for both platforms, except for iOS where you cannot connect a hardware device. 

NB! Seems Android is a version 34 problem. 

I have attached my project file in the original comment now.

Comment: Did you check in VisualStudio, under Android SDKs, that 34 is marked? Also maybe need to run 'Restore WorkLoads' manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-restore

Comment: @o_w yeah Android 34 is marked, also ran restore workloads as well.

Comment: ok I have some suggestions: 1. <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks> Use one, either 7.0 or 8.0 for both. 2. <TitleProduct Name</Title> Missing '>' After '<Title'. 3. <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">15.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion> Min target should have 'contains' condition, not '=='. 4. <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('net8.0'))"> Include iOS specific packages in your shared project, which will try to include and build on Android as well, separate the packages inclusion

Comment: @o_w this is just a sample of it because it was a work in progress as outlined in my original post. The issues you outlined are actually not there in the original file, I edited my input for simplicity sake. Thanks though much appreciated.